# Changing data types and using LIKE in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I an using a database that in my opinion was not set up in the most intuitive way. I have two tables I am trying to join. The store table has info about the store and has a store_id field that is stored as a 7 digit number in the varchar format. The transaction table has a transaction_id field that is set up as hstore and stored as "package_id"=>"10000417". I am trying to join the two tables on these fields.

I have attempted to cast the transaction_id field as a varchar, at the same time tried to use a subquery in the join statement to add the "package_id"=>" portion to the store_id field. Yielding no results. So I tried to use LIKE in the JOIN statement to add wildcards. Still having problems. Here is the code I tried when using LIKE:

```
SELECT t.amount
    ,t.quantity_sold
    ,t.unit
    ,cast(t.transaction_details as varchar) as join_field
    ,s.product_name
    ,s.product_category
    ,s.metrc_id
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN store_info s ON t.transaction_details = s.store_id
WHERE t.transaction_details LIKE '%store_id%'
```

I have tried a number of other variations. I am hoping someone can provide a hint for me on a better direction to go with trying to link these two tables.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT

I am used to using SQL Server as opposed to Postgresql. I have since done more research on the hstore data type and understand it slightly better. I am still having trouble joining the two tables. I managed to create a new column with only the ID number by using the following query.

```
SELECT *, transaction_details->'package_id' as ID
FROM transactions
```

I tried to JOIN by then calling that column to no avail, so I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN store_info s ON t.transaction_details->'package_id' = s.store_id
```

I also tried to cast to integer or varchar using the following

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN store_info s ON cast(t.transaction_details->'package_id' 
as varchar) = s.store_id
```

Sorry for being such a noob. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons.

1. The store id and transaction details don't match, by your descriptions of the values in these columns.
2. The `like` pattern is simply a string that looks like `'%store_id%'`.  The column value is not in the string (see below on how to do this).

You need something like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN
     store_info s
     ON t.transaction_details LIKE '%' || s.store_id || '%';
```

However, I doubt that will do want you want.  The store id should be at the beginning or end of transaction details, suggesting:

```
     ON t.transaction_details LIKE '%' || s.store_id
```

or:

```
     ON t.transaction_details LIKE s.store_id || '%'
```

And, you are correct that this is a very bad data structure.  At the very least, the ETL process should be parsing out the store information from the transaction.